# Unreal Engine 4 Blueprint Object initialization

Tags: constructor, unreal-engine4

I've just started using Unreal Engine 4, but whenever i choose Object as parent class for my new blueprint, i don't have any constructor (like Construction Script function for Actor)

How can i make a constructor?

I don't want to use Actor becaue the class is storing the equipment data for my character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. Technically Construction Script is not Constructor as you know it from C++. It's somewhat misleading name.

Technically C++ equivalent for Construction Script is AActor::OnConstruction(), not class Constructor.

You must also consider the fact that UObjects are not replicated by default. In future if you would want to make your inventory replicated, you would need to either switch to Actors (which is not that good idea), or write it in C++, where you can explicitly tell, which UObjects should replicate as part of Actor or ActorComponent.

https://github.com/iniside/GameInventorySystemPlugin

Here is Inventory Plugin I'm developing. It's still WIP, but basic functionality is now implemented and it should work with 4.6 version of engine. Right now it's combination of C++ and Blueprint. I also recommend rebuilding it from source if you want to try it out, since default binaries are build against source version of engine.

It should give you nice starting point, to either see how things are done, or just straight to use it.